# Bash/SH, Same command different output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "apple" | shasum -a 256

$ sh -x a.sh
+ echo -n apple
+ shasum -a 256
d9d20ed0e313ce50526de6185500439af174bf56be623f1c5fe74fbb73b60972  -
$ bash -x a.sh
+ echo -n apple
+ shasum -a 256
3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b  -
```

And the last one is correct.
Why is that? and how to solve it?

Comment: For reference, I get the last one if I try `csh` or `zsh` also. But I get the same result for all 4 if I omit `-n` from `echo`.

Comment: Moral of the story: if the output of the command differs, rethink your assumptions about its input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per POSIX, [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) supports no options.

Therefore, when `echo -n` is run with `sh`, it outputs *literal* `-n` instead of interpreting `-n` as the no-trailing-newline option:

```
$ sh -c 'echo -n "apple"'
-n apple                  # !! Note the -n at the beginning.
```

<sup>Note: Not *all* `sh` implementations behave this way; some, such as on Ubuntu (where `dash` acts as `sh`), *do* support the `-n` option, but the point is that you cannot *rely* on that, if your code must run on multiple platforms.</sup>

The *portable* POSIX-compliant way to print to stdout is to use the [`printf` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

```
printf %s "apple" | shasum -a 256
```